# Unable to connect Nest js to running mariadb docker container using typeOrm

Tags: mysql, mariadb, nestjs, typeorm

I am using typeOrm to try to connect to a docker container I am running on my machine.

Here's the command I used to run my container:

`docker run --name mariadbtest -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=vat -d mariadb/server:10.3`

My Nest js backend is utilizing a typeorm.config file with the following:

`export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: 'mariadb',
    host: 'mariadbtest',
    port: 3306,
    username: 'root',
    password: 'mypass',
    database: 'vat',
    entities: ['/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: true,
};`

Imported to my app.module like so:

`@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig),
],`

I'm getting the following error message when I run my app in dev mode:

`[Nest] 24000   - 02/18/2020, 8:31:56 PM   [ExceptionHandler] getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mariadbtest mariadbtest:3306 +52ms
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mariadbtest mariadbtest:3306`

Thanks everyone.

Comment: hint: 3606 != 3306

Comment: EDIT - that was a typo when I was writing my question. Doubled checked that they were both 3306 and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: is that the correct host for a mariadb? Usually host is an ip address or a url host, like localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: So I actually go this working with `host: 'localhost'`. I assume that if I explicitly name the host in my docker run command, that will be the host name I want to configure my backend to.